# How do you delete the indexed databases stored on your computer in Firefox?

Tags: database, firefox, indexeddb

In Opera you can simply type in `opera:webdatabases` in the address field and delete all the web SQL databases stored on your computer.

How do you do the same in Firefox? I need to delete an IndexedDB on my localhost to experiment with a fresh version.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is old, but there is a way to do this *in* Firefox:

1. Go to Tools -> Page Info
2. Go to the "Permissions" tab
3. Scroll down to "Maintain Offline Storage"
4. Click "Clear Storage"

Comment: ..aaaand that option is gone.

Comment: @that-ben it might have been moved

Comment: For FF 115, this is the way to do it:  

1.  Go to Tools -> Page Info
2.  Click the "Security" tab 
3.  Under "Privacy & History", click "Clear cookies and Site Data"

Answer (score 5):

I figured out  how to delete the databases. Windows stores user data separately on a per application basis (on Windows 7 in C:\Users\\AppData). So I found the Firefox Profiles folder in this directory, went to the indexedDB folder and deleted the sqlite files. Then I restarted Firefox and it worked! The full path of Windows 7 is like: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<*>.default\indexedDB

Answer (score 4):

I have found that running this code in console (Ctrl+Shift+K) is an easier solution:

```
indexedDB.deleteDatabase('MyDatabaseName').onsuccess=(function(e){console.log("Delete OK");})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a node script that deletes the indexedDB directory for every website.

```
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<*>.default\indexedDB
```

based on Aadit's answer.

```
    var userName = "myWindowsUserName";

var fs = require("fs");
var root = "C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\";
var dir = fs.readdirSync(root);

var deleteFolderRecursive = function (path) { // http://www.geedew.com/2012/10/24/remove-a-directory-that-is-not-empty-in-nodejs/
    if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function (file, index) {
            var curPath = path + "/" + file;
            if (fs.statSync(curPath).isDirectory()) { // recurse
                deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
            } else { // delete file
                fs.unlinkSync(curPath);
            }
        });
        fs.rmdirSync(path);
    }
};

var anyRemoved = false;
for(var i = 0; i < dir.length; i++) {
  if(/\.default$/.test(dir[i])) {
    var idbPath = root + dir[i] + "\\indexedDB";
    var idbDir = fs.readdirSync(idbPath);
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < idbDir.length; i2++) {
        anyRemoved = true;
        var rmDir = idbPath + "\\" + idbDir[i2];
        console.log("removing: " + rmDir);
        deleteFolderRecursive(rmDir);
    }
  }
}
if(anyRemoved === false)
  console.log("No indexedDB files were found.");

setTimeout(function () { }, 1000 * 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firefox indexedDB (Ubuntu)

`~/.mozilla/firefox-trunk/*.default/storage/persistent/<folder_to_delete>`

This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

In firefox, indexeddb can be deleted by:

1. Using `Ctrl + Shift (Alt) + Delete` and choosing to clear offline website data.
2. Deleting the file corresponding to individual websites. On linux, these files can be found at `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>.default/storage/persistent/<website>`

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu and probably most linux distros it's in your home directory

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<*>.default/indexedDB
```

Answer (score 1):

On OS X 10.10.2 and Firefox 36.0.1, I deleted

```
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/*.default/storage/default/<url>/idb
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have been moved down a directory or two. Instead of

```
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<*>.default\indexedDB
```

try

```
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<*>.default\storage\persistent\<site>
```