# What should I use for store data client-side so that datas wouldn't be deleted when clearing browsers history?

Tags: javascript

What should I use for store data client-side so that datas wouldn't be deleted when clearing browsers history? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What you *should* do is have the client log in and store the data on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually [Indexed DB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) is the standard browser-side storage approach which doesn't get dropped when user clears browser's history.

See these related Q&As:

- [No way to delete IndexedDB under Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125281/no-way-to-delete-indexeddb-under-google-chrome)
- [How do you delete the indexed databases stored on your computer in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614789/how-do-you-delete-the-indexed-databases-stored-on-your-computer-in-firefox)

This still true for major browsers *for now*. Maybe I'll need to retract this answer in a while...

Comment: Thank you , It's exactly what I looked for.

Comment: @daniel1234567 No problem! IndexedDB is a very interesting technology.

Comment: Fidemraizer Could you help me choose wrapper library so indexeddb would work on mobile devices? I want a light library only for this task(nothing fancy and complex like new commands and so on).

Comment: Fidemraizer Thank you one more time!

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the browser's history does just that. It doesn't clear cookies or local storage.  But `localStorage` is probably your best bet if you meant clearing cookies as `localStorage` is not cleared by clearing cookies. **[See this for more.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**

Comment: Thank You for your answer, unfortunelly I read that localStorage is deleted when browsers history got deleted. Here is the link to that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512449/does-localstorage-in-javascript-get-wiped-off-after-clearing-browser-history

Comment: That post is misleading. When clearing the browser's history, just the history is cleared. However, often when clear history is clicked, the option to clear other resources is also offered and if the user has those other resources checked, then yes, those other resources will be cleared.